# About how to retrieve the last insert data in sqlite

Tags: ios, sqlite

I just start to learn sqlite on ios.I want to get the data of last insert data.Actually I can do that using sqlite_lastinsert_rowid only when I first write some datas into the table .It's not what I want.I want to retrieve the last insert data just when I launch the software without write.So is there some better way to retrieve data in sqlite?

Answer (score 0):

If your data has something like a timestamp, get the record with the largest one.

Otherwise, you have to get the largest [rowid](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html).